# Cannot convert value of type 'UIBarButtonItem!' to expected argument type '_OptionalNilComparisonType'

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to follow the FoodTracker tutorial on Apple Developer.  Right now I'm on the section "[Implementing Navigation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson8.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH16-SW1)".

It looks like this tutorial was written for a previous version of Swift as the code doesn't work sometimes without having to change overridden method signatures.

Here's an example:

```
// This method lets you configure a view controller 
// before it's presented.
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, 
   sender: AnyObject?) {
```

On my version of Xcode (8.0) that method has to change to:

```
override func prepare(for: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
```

...so that it matches the appropriate method in the parent class/protocol that needs to be overridden.

The tutorial continues with the following line of code:

```
if saveButton == sender {
```

...which produces the error on the subject line.

I have spent the last few hours trying to fix this, searching online, trying to figure out why the optional sender Any? doesn't match a UIBarButtonItem but have been unsuccessful, so as a last resort I am posting here.  I have been attempting to follow a couple of books on iOS development, but I was running into problems with the code as well (doesn't work in the current version of Xcode(8.0)/Swift(3), so I decided to spend time on the official Apple tutorial.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: I wanted to add that I also downloaded the code at the end of the lesson and the code has the same problem.

Comment: Swift is a language with a strong type system. To compare two items the types must be the same. `Any` is the most unspecific type in Swift like an common denominator. If you have a distinct type on the left side you must cast `Any` to the same type on the right side. If you know that the sender is always `UIBarButtonItem` you can forced cast it down. If you don't know in case there are senders with multiple types, use optional binding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried casting your sender (Any?) as a UIBarButtonItem?

```
if saveButton == (sender as? UIBarButtonItem)
```

Comment: That is precisely the solution!  Thank you.

Comment: BTW, I reopened the project straight from the source download and learned that the tutorial has been created in Swift 2.3.  If I don't convert it to 3.0 when I open the project it runs as is in the old Swift syntax.